# Update a view concatenated column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a table called `Employee` with these columns:

```
EmpID, EmpName, HRA, Basics, Allowances
```

I have a created a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Emp 
AS 
   SELECT 
       EmpName AS 'Employee', 
       (HRA + Basics + Allowance) AS 'Salary' 
   FROM Employee
```

I want to update the salary so that it would be stored into the corresponding columns `HRA`, `Basics` and `Allowance`. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: You want to update it using the view?

Comment: Actually, this question was asked to me in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the `HRA`, `Basics`, and `Allowances` column using only the view because it is a computed column.  Consider that the server has no way of knowing how to divide the amount you provide for `Salary` between the 3 columns and it's obvious why this is so.

Comment: Yes. But the interviewer told me there is an option to do this. I want to know which is the way to do that?

Comment: @thevan If you had referenced the columns directly, those columns would be updatable, but you can't update a column that's derived from a computation.  See the discussion at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx on updatable views.  Perhaps the interviewer was wrong or you misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the computed column is not possible directly using view.
You can use Instead OF Trigger on view to handle such scenario.